# Recording caller's voice on conversation during call

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, voice-recording

Is it possible to record caller's voice while on a call on a non-jail-broken iPhone device? I have tried working on this using Libraries and I have also looked into VoIP. Just wanted to know is it possible without VoIP? Thank you in advance.
I have used

- [EZAudio](https://github.com/syedhali/EZAudio)
- [CallKit](https://github.com/naandonov-mm/iOS-10-Sampler)
- [plivo](https://www.plivo.com/)

Comment: no..Big no. Not possible. You are going to breach the Apple's security system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is **not permitted** for an app on a non-jailbroken device to record a call for security reasons. VoIP is the only way to achieve this functionality.